# Will the city of Prague be accessible during a marathon?

Tags: sightseeing, czech-republic, events, prague, weekends

I booked a weekend trip to Prague from may 24th until the 26th and just discovered that there will be a running event like a marathon.  Will the city be accessible? And if not,  what are the best places to visit on such a day? Our hotel is near the center of Mala Strana.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which running event would that be? I looked at several event calendars for Prague, and they all list only a marathon on May 11th.

In any case, I wouldn't be concerned; you're in walking distance of lots of sights, and the metro shouldn't be affected by such events anyway.

Comment: It's called the Mattoni Karlovy Vary half marathon

Comment: @TomDoes: here's a video of that event last year: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYNz7C7oVec - looks like neither the number of runners nor of spectators would make the city inaccessible and you could cross the track without problems in most places